# Logarithmic Differentiation of $x(3x^2-9)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I am trying to teach myself how to use logarithmic differentiation, but I'm not getting the right answer for some reason. I think it is because I may be improperly using log rules, but I can't find anything on how to use them with complicated terms like $3x^2-9$

$$y = x(3x^2-9)$$

Apply $\ln()$ to both sides.

$$\ln(y)=\ln(x(3x^2-9))$$

$$\ln(y)= \ln(x) + 2\ln(3x)-\ln9$$

$$\ln(y)= \ln(x) + 2\ln3 + 2\ln(x)-\ln9$$

Differentiate each term

$$\frac{1}{y}y'=\frac{1}{x}+0+\frac{2}{x}-0$$

Multiply both sides by $y$.

$$y'=(3x^3-9x)\frac{3}{x}$$

But when I use [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(x%5Cleft(3x%5E%7B2%7D-9%5Cright)%5Cright)) to solve the derivative and plug both derivatives into [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), I get different graphs.

Comment: There isn't a rule that says $\ln(a \pm b)=\ln(a) \pm \ln(b)$

Comment: $\ln(3x^2-9)\ne2\ln(3x)-\ln 9$.

Comment: So I can't separate $\ln(3x^2-9)$?

Comment: You can write $\ln{(3)}+\ln{(x^2-3)}$

Comment: A mistake arises when you separate $\ln(3x^2-9)$ into $\ln(3x^2)-\ln(9)$. The valid rules involve $\ln(AB), \ln(A/B),$ and $\ln(A^B)$.

Comment: The derivative of $\ln(3x^2-9)$ is just $\frac{(3x^2)'}{3x^2-9}=\frac{6x}{3x^2-9}$

Comment: Thanks everyone, I see what I did wrong. $y'=(3x^3-9x)(x^{-1}+\frac{2x}{x^2-3})$

Comment: @LuminousNutria I suspect that that product can be simplified. A lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct calculation: if you set $\; f(x)=x(3x^2-9)$, then
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac 1x+\frac{6x}{3x^2-9}=\frac{3x^2-9+6x^2}{f(x))}=\frac{9(x^2-1)}{f(x)},$$
whence $\;f'(x)=9(x^2-1)$.

Comment: can't you differentiate using product rule?

Comment: @mathpadawan: Of course, I can, but the O.P. wanted to know how  logarithmic differentiation works, and there are cases where it is particularly useful.  I agree this is not the best example to demonstrate its usefulness.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that $$\ln(x\cdot (3x^2-9))=\ln x+\ln(3x^2-9)\color{red}{\not =}\ln x +\ln(3x^2)-\ln 9$$